# Selenium Calendar Data Extraction

Tags: python, selenium

My code aims to cycle through the dates on this reservation site and check each of the day and timeslot for an availability.  Below is a simplified version of the part I am struggling with, which is that 'allentry' does not return all the dates that are selectable in the calendar.  It seems to only go up to 11-December.  I'm wondering how I can retrieve all the dates up to a specified end date and store it to allentry.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

PATH = "/Users/king/Desktop/Python/chromedriver.exe"
driver= webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.tablecheck.com/shops/peterluger/reserve")

driver.find_element_by_id("reservation_start_date").click()

#store the list of available dates from the calendar object to allentry
allentry = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'dw-cal-day')]")

#create a list to store all the dates that have been reviewed
list_entry = []

#store all the ones that you find into a list, and compare each time to ensure it is not in this list
for date in allentry:

    date_id = date.get_attribute('aria-label')
    
    #ignore those dates which are not selectable
    if date.get_attribute('aria-disabled') == 'true' or date_id is None or date_id in list_entry:
        pass
    else:
        list_entry += [date_id]                

driver.refresh()
new_list = []

#Specify the month OR exact day OR type of day that you want to check
target_condition = ['December']

for t_month in list_entry:
    for condition in target_condition:
        if condition in t_month:
            new_list.append(t_month)

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked inside the `website HTML DOM`, and I could see they do not have a `div` with `aria-label attribute` beyond Saturday, December 11.

So there is no way `allentry` will have entry after 11 Decemeber.

**HTML in text :**

```
<div role="button" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Saturday, December 11 " data-day="6" data-full="2021-11-11" class="dw-cal-day  dw-cal-day-diff dw-cal-day-v dwb-e dwb-nhl"><div class="dw-i  "><div class="dw-cal-day-fg">11</div><div class="dw-cal-day-frame"></div></div></div>
```

**Here is the snapshot for proof :**

[image]